# TensorFlow classification does not match actual output

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, linear-regression

I wrote a code in TensorFlow for linear classification. I generated the fake data based on a rule which is "If the difference is greater than x(some constant) the output should be [1,0] else the output should be [0,1]. Here is my code

```
def weight_variable(shape):
     initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
     return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
     initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
     return tf.Variable(initial)

def main(_):
# Import data

# Create the model
     x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
     W1 = weight_variable([2, 2])
     b1 = bias_variable([2])
     y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

# Define loss and optimizer'''
     y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
     cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y2))
     train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

     sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
     tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
     # Train
     for _ in range(10000):
         batch_xs, batch_ys = data_supplier.next_batch(100)
         sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

     # Test trained model
     test_batch_x, test_batch_y = data_supplier.test_data()
     correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y2, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
     accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
     print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_batch_x,
                                  y_: test_batch_y}))
     print(x.eval(feed_dict={x: test_batch_x, y_: test_batch_y}))
     print(y2.eval(feed_dict={x: test_batch_x, y_: test_batch_y}))
     print(y_.eval(feed_dict={x: test_batch_x, y_: test_batch_y}))
     print(W1.eval())
     print(b1.eval())
     print(cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={x: test_batch_x, y_: test_batch_y}))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
    FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

And here's the data_supplier code:

```
TOTAL_DATA_SIZE = 50000
TRAIN_DATA_SIZE = 40000
VALIDATION_DATA_SIZE = 5000
TEST_DATA_SIZE = 5000
COLUMNS = ["a", "b","output", "outputbar"]
FEATURES = ["a", "b"]
LABELS = ["output", "outputbar"]
training_set = pd.read_csv("train.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
training_set_features = training_set.as_matrix(columns=FEATURES)
training_set_labels = training_set.as_matrix(columns=LABELS)
test_set = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
test_set_features = test_set.as_matrix(columns=FEATURES)
test_set_labels = test_set.as_matrix(columns=LABELS)


def next_batch(BATCH_SIZE):

    k = np.random.randint(0,TRAIN_DATA_SIZE-BATCH_SIZE)
    return training_set_features[k:k+BATCH_SIZE], training_set_labels[k:k+BATCH_SIZE]


def test_data():

    return test_set_features, test_set_labels
```

And here's the output:

```
accuracy: 0.6852
Input: [[ 0.51166666  0.79333335]
 [ 0.85833335  0.21833333]
 [ 0.80333334  0.48333332]
 ..., 
 [ 0.28333333  0.96499997]
 [ 0.97666669  0.84833336]
 [ 0.57666665  0.21333334]]
Predictions: [[ 0.80804855  0.19195142]
 [ 0.78380686  0.21619321]
 [ 0.80210352  0.19789645]
 ..., 
 [ 0.80708122  0.19291875]
 [ 0.83949649  0.16050354]
 [ 0.76328743  0.23671262]]
Actual output: [[ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
Weights: [[ 0.3034386  -0.10369452]
 [ 0.29422989 -0.21103808]]
Bias: [ 0.5141086 -0.3141087]
Cross Entropy: 0.624272
```

The accuracy is meaningless currently as every prediction is classified into [1,0]. What is the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` in the way it is designed for: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.
The warning says that the function expects unscaled `logits`, i.e. you should not perform a softmax operation for `y2`: `y2 = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1`. For the test set, you will have to perform a softmax operation: `y_out_test = tf.nn.softmax(y2)` or something like that. 
Maybe this will already solve your problem.

If not, if only a single class is predicted, it is often a hint to an imbalance in the data set, i.e. that one class occurs much more frequently than the other. You should check whether this is the case for you. If so, you might find some advice on how to deal with this, for example here: http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/. I did not check this site in detail, so I cannot tell you whether it is particularly helpful, but you might want to consult some web pages if your data set is heavily imbalanced.